# Swift: how to convert from a string (like 5/3/17, 10:16 AM) to Date object

Tags: swift, date, firebase

So I took a current date and did stored theDate.description (which is something like 5/3/17, 10:16 AM) into my firebase database. When retrieving the data from my database, I want to be able to sort by that date, so I want to convert it back to a Date object. How do you do that?

I looked at some previous posts but they were all either old (with NSDate) or just didn't work. Thanks!

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
                    print("\n\nKEY AND VALUE")
                    print(key)
                    print(value)
                    print("\n\n")
                    var date1: Date = Date()
                    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
                    date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: value)!
                    let temp = historyListItem(keyEntered: key, dateEntered: date1)
                    self.historyKeysAndDateArray.append(temp)
                    print(value)
                }
```

^It gives me the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at this line: `date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: value)!`

value is a string in this format: 5/2/17, 3:15 PM

Comment: There are countless examples of converting a date string into a `Date` using `DateFormatter`.

Comment: link to one? I've searched a bunch of times and none of them worked

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried and clearly explain your issue.

Comment: alright, updated

Comment: Do you honestly believe that the string `5/2/17, 3:15 PM` is matched by the format `dd/MM/yyyy`? You need to the format to exactly match the string.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was the format that it was going to be made into. Ty for help. No need to be condescending

Comment: I'm not trying to be condescending, I'm trying to get you to think through the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy I see, thanks. So in this case, would it be dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy', 'hh:mm"?

Comment: See my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here. The main one being the wrong date format for the string. Here's the proper code with some other cleanup:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy, h:mm a"
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    print("\n\nKEY AND VALUE")
    print(key)
    print(value)
    print("\n\n")
    if let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: value) {
        let temp = historyListItem(keyEntered: key, dateEntered: date1)
        self.historyKeysAndDateArray.append(temp)
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Don't force-unwrap optionals. Your app will crash.

Also, create the formatter before the loop. It will be much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! However, what if the date was something like 12/23/17? That would be two extra characters, right?

Comment: When parsing, `M/d/yy` or `MM/dd/yy` will work for that format. Parsing a string into a `Date` is more lenient than converting a `Date` into a string. Those two formats would give different result strings depending on the value for the day and month. But that doesn't apply to your original question. Use the playground and play around with different dates and strings and formats and see what you get. You'll learn a lot.

Comment: Alright, thank you! This was very helpful. Also, sorry for calling you condescending, clearly you were just trying to help

Comment: Glad to help. Looking back at my earlier comment I can see that I could have worded it better.

Answer (score 0):

The date/time you are trying to format is: 5/2/17, 3:15 PM
Yet your dateFormatter is: dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
The dateFormat much match exactly to convert that string to a date type.
Where is the time and am/pm

Comment: I thought that was the format that it would be turned into or something, I'm an idiot. ty

Comment: I thought the same thing.  Date/time formats can vary wildly.  You must be very specific.